# strpos(): Argument #1 ($haystack) must be of type string, array given

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, strpos, php-8

I'm newbie in Laravel, and follow a free course in Laracast. This is link of my course [my_cource](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-8-from-scratch/episodes/11) (episode 11 at 2:49s).

Summary of my problem: I'm trying to make my code more declarative with what I wan't to do (more specific is make a class name: `Post`, and a method: `find()` inside this class). This file declare Post class:

**Model/Post.php**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

class Post
{
    public static function find($slug)
    {
        //don't write any thing in this function, 
        //i expected an blank page (not an error page like my bug)
    }
}
```

And this file direct url when user click:

**routes/web.php**:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Models\Post;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('posts');
});

Route::get('posts/{post}', function ($slug) {
    //find post with slug and pass it intos posts view (through $post variable)
    $post = Post::find($slug);
    return view([
        'post' => $post
    ]);

})
    ->where('post', '[A-z_-]+');
```

This file return Html page, it's view of user (what user see in browser):

**views/post.blade.php**:

```
<body>
    <article>
        <?= $post ?>
    </article>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what I expect:
[Expect result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gw3wJ.png)

But this is the real I received:
[strpos(): Argument #1 ($haystack) must be of type string, array given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BIrd.png)

> Error say: strpos(): Argument #1 ($haystack) must be of type string,
> array given

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the return, method view should have a string, then maybe followed by the array data

```
Route::get('posts/{post}', function ($slug) {
    $post = Post::find($slug);

    return view('post', [
        'post' => $post
    ]);

})
    ->where('post', '[A-z_-]+');
```

Answer (score 2):

I've already fixed it ;) Thanks.
The issue was

```
php8.0-mbstring & php8.0-xml
```

just install them :)

Answer (score 2):

Same issue `strpos(): Argument #1 ($haystack) must be of type string, array given` but on \vendor\fruitcake\laravel-cors. If u have same condition, maybe u can check link this https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors/issues/565